# Remove extra column listview WPF vb.net

Tags: wpf, vb.net, listview

I've looked through most of the answers here regarding this question but most say to simply switch to a datagrid.  In winForm i could also just simply remove the column at runtime but doesn't look like i can do that in WPF.  Is there any xaml code I can do to get rid of that extra column on the right since I don't see i can programatically remove that column at run time?

I would rather not just convert over to a datagrid because of all the time I spent working my program around a listview, is this possible to get rid of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the `ListView` itself left-aligned, effectively sizing itself to its contents, rather than to it's container:

```
<ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left">
  <!-- ... -->
</ListView>
```